# Simultaneous actions on action event on one graph

Tags: angular, highcharts

I have created two pie graphs in one graph using angular-highcharts, now I want to perform same action on second pie graph on click of first graph and vice-versa. When I click on any section of first pie graph, then it goes selected and sliced too., at the same time I want to perform same action on second one.
This is how, I am creating two pie graphs, any help will be appreciated, thanks in Advance.

```
const pChart = new Chart({
                    chart: {
                        type: 'pie',
                        styledMode: true
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        pie: {
                            allowPointSelect: true,
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                formatter: function () {
                                    return Math.round(this.percentage * 100) / 100 + ' %';
                                },
                                distance: -30,
                                color: '#000'
                            },
                            colors: ['#f7a35c', '#90ed7d'],
                            size: 180,
                            borderColor: 'none',
                            shadow: true
                        },
                        series: {
                            point: {
                                events: {
                                    legendItemClick: function () {
                                        return false; // <== returning false will cancel the default action
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            events: {
                                click: (event) => {
                                    console.log('event', event);
                                    for (let j = 0; j < this.qecData.length; j++) {
                                        this.select[j] = this.qecData[j].reasonForDebit === event.point.name;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    series: [
                        {
                            name: 'Frequency',
                            data: freqData,
                            center: ['20%', '60%'],
                            showInLegend: true,
                            startAngle: 270,
                            title: {
                                align: 'center',
                                text: 'Frequency Graph',
                                verticalAlign: 'top',
                                y: -50,
                                style: {
                                    color: '#869ca7'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'Amount',
                            data: amtData,
                            center: ['80%', '60%'],
                            showInLegend: false,
                            startAngle: 180,
                            title: {
                                align: 'center',
                                text: 'Amount Graph',
                                verticalAlign: 'top',
                                y: -50,
                                style: {
                                    color: '#869ca7'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });
```

Comment: Please create snippet of your issue

Comment: As @Justcode said, you can go over to any platform that allows for creating angular app online and create a minimal reproduction of your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using `series.pie.point.events.click` callback when you have access to the point that was clicked. There you will find an index of this point and chart index which allows you to invoke the `select` method on point with the same index from the second chart. Check the code and demo posted below. It uses the **highcharts-angular official wrapper** that I recommend you to use (can be downloaded here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular).

**app.module.ts :**

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { HighchartsChartModule } from "highcharts-angular";
import { ChartComponent } from "./chart.component";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ChartComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, HighchartsChartModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**chart.component.html :**

```
<div class="boxChart__container">
  <div>
    <highcharts-chart
      id="container"
      [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
      [constructorType]="chartConstructor"
      [options]="chartOptions"
      [callbackFunction]="chartCallback"
      [(update)]="updateFromInput"
      [oneToOne]="true"
      style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;"
    >
    </highcharts-chart>
    <highcharts-chart
      id="container"
      [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
      [constructorType]="chartConstructor"
      [options]="chartOptions"
      [callbackFunction]="chartCallback"
      [(update)]="updateFromInput"
      [oneToOne]="true"
      style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;"
    >
    </highcharts-chart>
  </div>
</div>
```

**chart.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
import * as HighchartsMore from "highcharts/highcharts-more";
import * as HighchartsExporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting";

HighchartsMore(Highcharts);
HighchartsExporting(Highcharts);

@Component({
  selector: "app-chart",
  templateUrl: "./chart.component.html"
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {
  title = "app";
  chart;
  charts;
  updateFromInput = false;
  Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartConstructor = "chart";
  chartCallback;
  chartOptions = {
    chart: {
      plotBackgroundColor: null,
      plotBorderWidth: null,
      plotShadow: false,
      type: "pie"
    },
    title: {
      text: "Browser market shares in January, 2018"
    },
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: "{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>"
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: "pointer",
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: "<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %",
          style: {
            color:
              (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) ||
              "black"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: "Brands",
        colorByPoint: true,
        point: {
          events: {
            click: function() {
              this.series.chart.chartComponent.showCharts(this);
            }
          }
        },
        data: [
          {
            name: "Chrome",
            y: 61.41,
            sliced: true,
            selected: true
          },
          {
            name: "Internet Explorer",
            y: 11.84
          },
          {
            name: "Firefox",
            y: 10.85
          },
          {
            name: "Edge",
            y: 4.67
          },
          {
            name: "Safari",
            y: 4.18
          },
          {
            name: "Sogou Explorer",
            y: 1.64
          },
          {
            name: "Opera",
            y: 1.6
          },
          {
            name: "QQ",
            y: 1.2
          },
          {
            name: "Other",
            y: 2.61
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

  constructor() {
    const self = this;

    self.chartCallback = chart => {
      self.chart = chart;
      self.chart.chartComponent = self;
      self.charts = Highcharts.charts;
    };
  }

  showCharts(point) {
    const chart = point.series.chart,
      chartIndex = chart.index,
      pointIndex = point.index,
      secondChartIndex = chartIndex === 0 ? 1 : 0,
      secondChart = this.charts[secondChartIndex],
      secondChartPoint = secondChart.series[0].points[pointIndex];

    secondChartPoint.select();
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**Demo:** 
https://codesandbox.io/s/nw8yq0n9ol

**API reference:** 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.point.events.click 
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#select